# Connection with MySQL 5.6 local server fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to connect from a Java Web application to a database called "libros", but when I try to run the application from the internal server (I'm using STS 3.6.1), I get the following error:

```
oct 09, 2014 7:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet ControladorLibros lanzó excepción
com.arquitecturajava.DataBaseException: Error de SQL
    at com.arquitecturajava.DataBaseHelper.seleccionarRegistros(DataBaseHelper.java:138)
    at com.arquitecturajava.Libro.buscarTodos(Libro.java:101)
    at com.arquitecturajava.ControladorLibros.doGet(ControladorLibros.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'libros'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.arquitecturajava.DataBaseHelper.seleccionarRegistros(DataBaseHelper.java:92)
    ... 25 more
```

I know there is the "libros" table, because I created it myself and consult the MySQL Workbench. Clarified that the MySQL Server is local, as well as the application.

Further, the strangest thing is that if I connect with the same application to an online MySQL, no error is displayed.

I am connecting to the latest MySQL JDBC connector and also tried other previous versions, but the problem is the same.

Of course, I appreciate your attention.

Gustavo Echenique

Comment: The exception is not saying there is no "libros" table, but there is no libros database. It would help to show com.arquitecturajava.DataBaseHelper.seleccionarRegistros(DataBaseHelper.java:92).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting " MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'libros' ".

You initially said libros was a database; but in a later statement called it a table - Check that you haven't created a table called libros, and not a database. Which is one potential cause for this type of error.

For further help, provide the create statement used, as well as the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are connecting to the correct host and that the MySQL host you are connecting to has the 'libros' database.

Also, check if the user you are using in your JDBC configuration have access to the 'libros' database.

Try this command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am compelled to apologize for the time I lost them.

The database is called "arquitecturajava" and has a table called "libros".

When I tested with MySQL online, I called the database as "libros", so when I tried the local server did not work.

Thank you very much for your help.